# Reading data from running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I know java thread related questions have been asked many times, but I have not been able to piece together an answer to my question. I am still new to thread programming, so excuse my ignorance.

I undestand the issues related with consistency and need to synchronize appropriately as needed. The question is about invoking a method on an object that is in the thread that is currently being executed. Consider the following example (this is experimental so excuse any poor design choice):

1. I have a JSP that does some searching and returns results. The response must be sent to the user within 10 seconds (irrespective of whether the search was able to finish).
2. The JSP creates a ThreadPoolExecutor and uses is to kick off a search thread.
3. The JSP goes to sleep for 2 seconds.
4. The JSP wakes up and checks if the search thread had any results. The search obj provides a method getCurrentResultsCount() that returns an int of count of results found so far.
5. Steps 3 & 4 are repeated 5 times then a response is sent to the user. The search thread is allowed to continue for as long as needed (upon completion, the results are stored in servlet context or database and can be accessed later)

My code looks like this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
SearchWidget searchWidget = new SearchWidget(searchTerm);
Future<?> searchWidgetFuture = pool.submit(searchWidget);
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("1. Results so far:" + searchWidget.getCurrentResultsCount());
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("2. Results so far:" + searchWidget.getCurrentResultsCount());
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("3. Results so far:" + searchWidget.getCurrentResultsCount());
...
...
```

Is there anything wrong or risky with invoking the getCurrentResultsCount() method the way I'm doing it? It seems to be working fine on low volume usage, but am I risking issues if there is higher volume?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong or risky with invoking the getCurrentResultsCount() method the way I'm doing it?

No, there is nothing wrong as long as `getCurrentResultsCount()` is accessing some synchronized field since the shared data is being updated and accessed in two different threads.  I'd recommend using `AtomicInteger` to store such information.

> It seems to be working fine on low volume usage, but am I risking issues if there is higher volume?

You are paying a performance penalty for updating a `volatile` field (inside of `AtomicInteger`) but it is relatively small.  On the surface there is nothing to worry about.  The increase the number of background tasks is going to significantly overshadow any sharing of data between your JSPs and the threads.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. Always useful to get some expert input. On the topic of synchronization, is there a true need for syncing access to a variable if only one thread updates it and only one thread reads it? Say the search widget keeps adding results in an ArrayList, and the JSP periodically checks how many results there are (or even gets the latest added results from the ArrayList inside the search widget), do I need to worry about syncing access to the ArrayList? (assuming the JSP code keeps track of the last fetched index, so no records are being deleted from the ArrayList).

Comment: There is a need for synchronization if the values must be properly updated.  Otherwise your JSP could never see the right value.  It wouldn't throw but it would be unpredictable.  In terms of the `ArrayList`, the only time you can share an `ArrayList` between threads is if it is not being changed.  If the writer is making any changes, it could cause an unsynchronized reader to throw an exception.

Comment: All in all, worrying about these performance problems is premature optimization.  You are writing a web-app and the synchronization is going to be a small, small percentage of the server load @Mohammad.

Comment: I guess I'm straying into premature optimization because I'm afraid of running into thread issues that I may not be able to troubleshoot due to my inexperience with threading. Thanks.